# Using appcache with php & database

Tags: html, html5-appcache

I'm developing web apps using jQuery Mobile. These apps use a database to get prices, etc (using php).
I'm also using appcache to be able to use the apps offline.

```
<html manifest="manifest.appcache">
```

This is all working perfectly. But when I'm online, I don't want the apps to use the appcache.
How do I do that?

I can check wether I'm online/offline by checking if a file is available:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://someurl.com/online.txt',
    type:'HEAD',
    error: function()
    {
        console.log('offline');
    },
    success: function()
    {
        console.log('online');
    }
});
```

However I can't find anything to have the page **not** use the appcache..

Am I missing something?

Comment: How is the app using apache? Can you show the calls to the server?

Comment: I don't have access to the server. But does apache have anything to do with this?

Comment: I dont understand "when I´m online, dont use apache"..how can you use an apache web server when you´re offline?

Comment: I'm talking about appcache (application cache), not apache ;)

Comment: lol. sorry cant help you right now. I think I should go to bed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step by step solution:

1. Check if you're online/offline
2. If you're online, run a php script which adds a # at the end of the appcache manifest. This is because the cache will be updated if the manifest has changed.
3. Swap the cache and refresh the page

After i finally got it working i noticed it didn't work in Firefox because of the swapCache() function. (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=769171)
Lucky me my users don't use Firefox..