# How to get appcache work with PHP (or any server side) scripting?

Tags: javascript, php, html, offline, html5-appcache

HTML5 `appcache` is a good way to cache resources in the client side and make them available when the user goes offline. I was playing around with this technology for sometime now, and it works pretty good so far with static resources like `html`, `css`, `js`, `images` etc.

Now I have come to a situation where I have the need to integrate some `php` functionality into my application. For the sake of simplicity lets say my `show_tasks.php` does this,

```
<?php
    // Print the list of task names from the database.
    printMyTasks();
?>
```

So I have put cached this page inside my `myCache.appcache` file like this,

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#v1.0

show_tasks.php
```

Now the **issue** is this.

> When the user accesses this page for the first time (given he is
>   online), the browser caches the html page along with the list of tasks
>   those were there at that moment. But after that, even when he is
>   online, it does not connect to the database and fetch the latest data.
>   Instead it always shows the cached version which was cached in the
>   first run.

I understand that in order to update the cache in the client side, a change must be done to the `show_tasks.php` file itself (not the data it manipulates) and also the `myCache.appcache` file should be updated. (In my case, a change to the `show_tasks.php` won't happen)

I am looking for a solution so that my application works in a way such that,

- If the user is online, read the tasks from database and show them.
  (Don't show the cached version)
- If the user is offline, show the cached version, but also with the
  most recently updated data. (The list of tasks fetched when he
  accessed it online the last time)

I have looked into [`Using appcache with php & database`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19426717/using-appcache-with-php-database) question too. But I am wondering if there is another way of achieving this. (Probably using some client side functionality) Obviously I am willing to use Javascript/Jquery.
What will be a good approach to handle this scenario?

Comment: for all i know, you need to change your manifest file. If you do this every time the user accesses data from the server, you should be good to go.

Comment: Yep, that was the only approach I also could find out on the web. Too bad the option to switch between online/offline according to the condition is not there in the manifest.